# Applied mathematics commonly needed in the following industries

Tags: mathematical-modeling, research

I was just wondering if anyone could shed more light on specific topics in applied mathematics or other skills (programming, etc) commonly used in the following industries: oil and gas, aviation/aeronautics. In particular, I'm interested in how mathematical modelling could be applied in these industries (from the perspective of a Maths PhD student). Would be quite interested to hear from others with experience in any of these industries. I've heard a lot about CFD in aeronautics-I was wondering if there were any others.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics 2012 Report on Mathematics in Industry](http://www.siam.org/reports/mii/2012/index.php) is what you're looking for, specifically the [trends and case studies](http://www.siam.org/reports/mii/2012/role.php) on the role of mathematical sciences in industry.

Comment: thanks so much for that link-lots of useful information there.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Computational Fluid Dynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_fluid_dynamics), as you mention, which can also be used for oil and gas flows (and mud flow when drilling), there's also [control theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_theory) and [optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization), including [flow networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_network) to model pipe systems.